# g++ file format not recognized; treating Object.o as linker script

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, g++, linker-errors

**Object.hpp**

```
#ifndef OBJECT_HPP
#define OBJECT_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Object {
  private:
    sf::Image image;

  public:
    float x;
    float y;
    int width;
    int height;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    virtual void update();
};

#endif
```

**Object.cpp**

```
void Object::update() {

}
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
LIBS=-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

all:
    @echo "** Building mahgame"

State.o : State.cpp
    g++ -c State.cpp

PlayState.o : PlayState.cpp
    g++ -c PlayState.cpp

Game.o : Game.cpp
    g++ -c Game.cpp

Object.o : Object.cpp
    g++ -c Object.cpp

Player.o : Player.cpp
    g++ -c Player.cpp

mahgame : Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o
    g++ -o mahgame Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o $(LIBS)

    #g++ -c "State.cpp" -o State.o
    #g++ -c "PlayState.cpp" -o PlayState.o
    #g++ -c "Game.cpp" -o Game.o
    #g++ -c "Object.hpp" -o Object.o
    #g++ -c "Player.hpp" -o Player.o
    #g++ -o mahgame Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o $(LIBS)

clean:
    @echo "** Removing object files and executable..."
    rm -f mahgame

install:
    @echo '** Installing...'
    cp mahgame /usr/bin

uninstall:
    @echo '** Uninstalling...'
    rm mahgame
```

Here's the error I get when building (after building, it's a linker error):

```
/usr/bin/ld:Object.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:Object.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any idea of what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a makefile, this example is not complete, and I really doubt it's minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Were you, by any chance, using ccache?
I just had a very similar problem to yours and omitting ccache in the compilation solved it.

Answer (score 0):

makefiles are of the form:

```
xxx.o : xxx.cpp
   g++ -c xxx.cpp
```

Yours doesn't look anything like that.  So, change yours to be:

```
LIBS=.....

[EDIT]
all : mahgame rmerr

rmerr :
   rm -f err
[/EDIT]

State.o : State.cpp
   g++ -c State.cpp 2>>err

PlayState.o : PlayState.cpp
   g++ -c PlayState.cpp 2>>err

.....

mahgame : Game.o State.o .....
   g++ -o mahgame Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o $(LIBS) 2>>err
```

Note that these are your first steps, there are far better ways of writing makefiles that do not include every detail of your source files/object files/etc.

Comment: g++ -o mahgame Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
g++: error: Game.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: State.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: PlayState.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: Object.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: Player.o: No such file or directory

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Post your actual makefile (note my modification to the order of mine)

Comment: IIRC the `mahgame: Game.o ...` line needs to be after it's dependencies (see - note my modification to the order of mine `comment`)

Comment: Check my edit on main question, I put the mahgame: .... in the end, and I get: "State.o command not found".

Comment: Your `xxx.o : xxx.cpp` lines need to start in the first column.  Right now they are considered to be commands of `all` (as does your `mahgame : ....` line)

Comment: See my edits to your original post (indenting in the makefile)

Comment: @KevinDTimm The last time I used make, I don't recall that the order for rules made any difference at all. It's been a few years, though, so perhaps that has changed in more recent versions.

Comment: @Code-Guru: the order of the rules does matter, but the OP has bigger problems.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/7aa2e6bcf0ec50cd6ace So I tried that, but it only builds State.o, the rest of the code isn't executed.

Comment: Note too the down votes WITHOUT COMMENT - don't be a chicken, tell me why (or post your own CORRECT solution)

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile looks perfect, if a little verbose, and missing the header dependencies. I assume the shell commands have a leading tab character. I assume your build command is `make mahgame`.

As you said, you have a linker error. `Object.o` does not appear to be a valid `.o`. Get the compiler to re-generate it.

```
$ rm Object.o
$ make mahgame
g++ -c Object.cpp
g++ -o mahgame Game.o State.o PlayState.o Object.o Player.o...
```

Comment: I "rm *.o" many times, rebuilt everything, but I still get that linker error.

Comment: So compile `Object.cpp` by hand and have a look at the generated object file. `$ g++ -c Object.cpp`, `$ file Object.o` (my system says "Object.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped"), maybe `$ objdump -f Object.o`.